# Using sed to replace/remove accented Latin characters

Tags: linux, replace, sed

I got a mysql dump with several letters used in Spanish, such as: á, é, í, ó, ú and ñ.

I'm trying to import this dump onto a local database, but the resulting tables do not display the letters correctly. For instance, "colección" appears as "colecciÃ³n" on the web, and as "colecciÃƒÂ³n" in the SQL dump.

I cannot currently access the original database, so it occurred to me to try to replace the text using `sed` with the code that the database actually understands. In the case of "ó" it should be saved as "Ã³" to the database (which is identical to how it is displayed on the web).

I tried replacing it using something like this: `sed -e 's/ÃƒÂ³/Ã³' dump.sql` but I get an error that says:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command.
```

I understand the error is due to the codes I'm using, but I have no way to spell them correctly in the terminal without the whole thing going nuts in the prompt (characters get out of place, cannot longer use delete, etc).

What would be the correct way to use `sed` to achieve this? I realize there could be an easier way to fix the SQL dump, but I'd like to see if `sed` can do this (for learning purposes), before I mess with the original database again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminate your sed command with a `/`:

```
sed -e 's/ÃƒÂ³/Ã³/' dump.sql
```